# How can I limit the days returned in the date module to today's and future dates only?

Tags: datetime

I have the Date module installed on Drupal 7 (version 7.x-2.5) and I am attempting to disable the selection of past dates within the date popup.

```
$form['ratesDateSelect'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Arrival Date',
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#size' => 21,
    '#maxlength' => 100,
    '#date_flexible' => 0,
    '#date_year_range' => (date('Y')) . ':+5',
    '#attributes' => array('autocomplete' =>'off','readonly' => 'readonly'),
    '#description' => '',
    '#value' => array('date' => $date),
    '#date_format' => 'D d M Y',
    '#required' => FALSE,
);
```

I have limited the popup to return this year and five years into the future, but I also need to restrict it so that people cannot select past days.

I have managed to do this in another project using pure javascript, using the datepicker param: `minDate: 0`

Comment: Tale a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/1689646#comment-7343030
The solution works for me fine wihtou any hack in date module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out shortly after posting, but it required a little bit of "hacking" of the date module.

To get this working I added a new '#settings' variable onto the date_popup type so it would look like ..

```
$form['ratesDateSelect'] = array(
'#title' => 'Arrival Date',
'#type' => 'date_popup',
'#default_value' => '',
'#size' => 21,
'#maxlength' => 100,
'#date_flexible' => 0,
'#date_year_range' => (date('Y')) . ':+5',
'#attributes' => array('autocomplete' =>'off','readonly' => 'readonly'),
'#description' => '',
'#value' => array('date' => $date),
'#date_format' => 'D d M Y',
'#required' => FALSE,
'#settings' => array('minDate'=>'0'),
);
```

on the form element and then I added this code into date_popup.module (around line 336) after the settings array.

```
$user_settings = $element['#settings'];
foreach($user_settings as $setting_key => $setting_val) {
    $settings[$setting_key] = $setting_val;
}
```

This allowed me to inject javascript settings/options so that I can restrict the dates returned from now into the future.

Ryan

Comment: For any future visitors who stumble on this problem: as of Date 7.x-2.6 the hack is no longer necessary. A feature with the same approach was added to the module. Instead of `#settings` you'll just have to use `#datepicker_options`. To see an example you can check my answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11836/drupal-7-custom-form-date-popup-element

Comment: I'd add that there's also a module for that: [Date restrictions](http://drupal.org/project/date_restrictions).